# margin to border not showing in chrome/safari

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari

Strange problem:

```css
         .nav_active {
           padding: 8px 0 8px 0;
           border-top: 5px solid #2778ad;
           border-bottom: 5px solid #2778ad;
           border-left: none;
           border-right: none;
         }
```

```html
 <span class="nav_active"><a class="active" href="/home">Home</a></span>
```

In FF this works fine, there are two 5px borders with 8px distance to the link on top and bottom. In chrome, the lines are directed to the link-text. If i make borders on the left and right side to, it works also in chrome.

Anyone an idea why this doesn't work on chrome?

Answer (score 2):

Use `block or inline-block` element:

```
.nav_active {
  padding: 8px 0 8px 0;
  border-top: 5px solid #2778ad;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #2778ad;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  display: inline-block;/*now padding-top,padding-bottom gets affected properly*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The border is indeed showing, but it is outside the window. It is "pushed" outside the viewable area (The browser window/body in fullscreen, the snippet preview box here on SO).

To proof this, let's push the whole thing down by 10px:

```css
.nav_active {
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 8px 0 8px 0;
    border-top: 5px solid #2778ad;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #2778ad;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<span class="nav_active"><a class="active" href="/home">Home</a></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem but only in safari and solved adding 'position:relative'

```
.nav_active {
       padding: 8px 0 8px 0;
       border-top: 5px solid #2778ad;
       border-bottom: 5px solid #2778ad;
       border-left: none;
       border-right: none;
       /*Added this line*/
       position:relative;
}
```